# Valid application of integration by parts for piecewise functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Consider the integral
$$
\int_{0}^{n} \left[
  f(x)\cdot \left(\color{blue} {x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}} \right) 
  \right] \mathrm{d}x 
$$
where $f$ is $k\ge 1$ times differentiable. I should reduce this integral to some expression which involves higher derivatives of $f$ (which can still be under an integral sign) meaning I have to find the antiderivative for the blue expression. I know how I would compute a definite integral of the form
$$
\int_{0}^{t}\left( {x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}} \right)  \mathrm{d}x 
$$
which yields the term
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left( t-\left\lfloor t \right\rfloor \right)^2
 - \frac{1}{2}(t-\left\lfloor t \right\rfloor)
$$
but can I really apply the integration by parts formula on this to obtain
$$
\int_{0}^{n} \left[
  f(x)\cdot \left( {x-\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor-\frac{1}{2}} \right) 
  \right] \mathrm{d}x 
=  \left[ \frac{1}{2}\left( x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \right)^2
 - \frac{1}{2}(x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor)f(x) \right]_0^n +\\[15pt] \int_{0}^{n} 
 \left[ \left( \frac{1}{2}\left( x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor \right)^2
 - \frac{1}{2}(x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor) \right) f'(x) \right]\mathrm{d}x 
$$
or is this not allowed?

Comment: You may want to write $$\int_0^nf(x) \, \left(x-\lfloor x \rfloor -\frac{1}{2}\right) \, dx=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\int_j^{j+1}f(x) \, \left(j -\frac{1}{2}-x\right) \, dx,$$ and now use integration by parts.

Comment: @AnuragA this makes much sense, thanks. Shouldn't it be $\left(x-j-\frac{1}{2}\right)$ then?

Comment: Yes, I made a typo.

Comment: @AnuragA does this work even though there is a discontinuity at $x = j+1$?

Answer (score 1):

What you did is backed up by a [generalized version of integration by parts theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Validity_for_less_smooth_functions) when one of the functions is absolutely continuous and the other one Lebesgue integrable.

$f$ is absolutely continuous as it is continuously differentiable. And the other one is Lebesgue integrable as it is piecewise continuous.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm only allowed to use arguments built upon the Riemann integral